# JavaScript Canvas Transform Text

Tags: javascript, canvas, text, transform

I have the following problem:
I need to transform text on a HTML canvas, e.g. give it a trapezoid shape.
Here's what I tried:

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, 0);
context.lineTo(200, 0);
context.lineTo(100, -100);
context.lineTo(0, -100);
context.closePath();
context.clip();
context.fillText("Hello World", this.x, this.y);
```

As you might have guessed, the text gets cut off instead of transformed to fit the shape. Below are images of what I am trying to do and what I managed to do.

Any help is appreciated :)

What I managed to do:

[image: What I managed to do:]

What I want to do:

[image: What I want to do:]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305104/how-to-do-perspective-view-with-html5-canvas will help you. Canvas2d does not support such a perspective transform.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is get a dummy canvas element in which you put your normal text, then you can apply your own maths to the pixel color values in `textCtx.getImageData` onto another imageData array that you create, so you can then put that into another canvas with the correct transform with `transformedTextCtx.putImageData`, and finally draw its canvas onto the original context with `ctx.drawImage`.

I'm going to assume you know the kind of maths that you want to apply, and if not I suggest you look into skewing and scaling, and find out how you can combine the two.

The mdn resources for the `imageData` methods are in the "Pixel Manipulation" subsection of the canvas rendering context page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D#Pixel_manipulation

Answer (score -1):

#### General Answer: `How to transform text`

You can transform your text (or anything else) by using `canvasContext.setTransform` before drawing. You don't need any second canvas.

Examples:

- `canvasContext.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);` is the default
- `canvasContext.setTransform(0.5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);` reduces width to 50%
- `canvasContext.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0);` reduces height to 50%

#### Specific Answer:

I couldn't figure this out quickly. I'll leave it up to the next user to figure it out.