# Drawing the Floor tiles with angles using Canvas HTML5

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I was developing an application for the Tiles manufacturer and for that I was using the HTML5 Canvas. On selection of the tiles The wall and floor should be feel with selected tiles. For the wall rectangle it was pretty straight forward and I was succeeded with that but when used the same for the floor, It didn't look like a floor tiles. Some transformation / rotate / Angle was missing.

I search through blogs to have a some angle in the floor tiles but failed to find proper solution.

Below is the image that I get from my code and below is the code sample too.

[image]

Code:-

```
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>

<script>
        var sources = {
                wallTile: './assets/tile_347.jpg',
                floorTile: './assets/tile_390.jpg',
            };

     function drawPattern(wallimg, floorimg, size, rectY) {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');

            canvas.width = 1366;
            canvas.height = 800;

            var tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var tCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

            tempCanvas.width = size;
            tempCanvas.height = size;
            tCtx.drawImage(wallimg, 0, 0, wallimg.width, wallimg.height, 0, 0, size, size);

            var tempFloorCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var tFloorCtx = tempFloorCanvas.getContext("2d");
            tempFloorCanvas.width = size;
            tempFloorCanvas.height = size;
            tFloorCtx.drawImage(floorimg, 0, 0, floorimg.width, floorimg.height, 0, 0, size, size);
            tFloorCtx.fill();
            tFloorCtx.setTransform(1,1,-0.5,1,30,10);
            tFloorCtx.rotate(50);

            // use getContext to use the canvas for drawing
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
           //  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(tempCanvas, 'repeat');
        //    ctx.rotate(0);
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(0,rectY,canvas.width, 400);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();

            var roomImg = new Image();
            roomImg.src = './assets/room11.png';
            roomImg.onload = function() {
                ctx.drawImage(roomImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                ctx.restore();
            }

            ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(tempFloorCanvas, 'repeat');
            ctx.beginPath();

            ctx.rect(0,400,canvas.width, 400);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();

            ctx.restore();


        }

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = './assets/wallTile.jpg';
        img.onload = function(){
            var wallimg = this;
            var floorimg = new Image();
            floorimg.src = './assets/floorTile.jpg';
            floorimg.onload = function(){
                drawPattern(wallimg, this, 100, 0);
            }
        }


    </script>
```

If there is another solution to implement the feature or If there are third party plugins which can transform my canvas to some angle to be look like a floor of the room, then please let me know.

I am new to canvas and html5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do perspective view with html5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305104/how-to-do-perspective-view-with-html5-canvas)

Comment: Thanks tif for the info, but I follow that thread, I didn't get the one which I am looking for.  I want to add some angle / rotate / transform of the floor tiles that looks like a floor of the room. Can you have some different idea on that ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the name implies, the 2D context is intended to do 2D stuff and doesn't offer any 3D functionality out of the box - affine transforms cannot be used to transform anything in 3D space.

Although it's fully possible to implement 3D functions manually, you would probably be better off looking into WebGL which *does* give you all 3D functionality that you would need in this case.

If you're not familiar with the concepts of WebGL, you could look into [three.js](https://threejs.org/) which does all the nitty gritty stuff for you (setting up shaders etc.) and provide an easy to use API. It also provides a 2D renderer in case your app is run on a browser/computer without WebGL/GPU support. You do need to familiarize yourself with basic 3D concepts though.

If you don't have the content as objects you can combine rendering a floor as an object (flat rectangle which you can produce inside three.js), and insert the remaining graphics as sprites on top (with obvious limitations that the room is in a fixed view, i.e. not being able to rotate/move around the room wo/ looking weird).

As to 2D context and 3D perspective: have a look at one of my [older answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17816375/1693593) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36381584/1693593). Just note that these examples are not meant for production use.